# Metaio sdk cannot read json file

Tags: mysql, json, ajax, web-services, metaio

so im trying to read json files that contain strings from MySQL that have been encoded to json for my quiz application.

```
    <script>
   $.ajax({
          url: 'http://museumjn.neti.net/webservice/quiz.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'get',
          cache: true,
          success: function(data){

         // Kuis 1 

           $('p#quiz1').append(data[1]['Quiz'] +'<br>')
           $('form[name=quiz1').append('<input id="jawabana" type="radio" name="quiz1" value="a">' + data[1]['Jawabana'] + '<br>')
           $('form[name=quiz1').append('<input id="jawabana" type="radio" name="quiz1" value="b">' + data[1]['Jawabanb'] + '<br>')
           $('form[name=quiz1').append('<input id="jawabana" type="radio" name="quiz1" value="c">' + data[1]['Jawabanc'] + '<br>')
           $('form[name=quiz1').append('<input id="jawabana" type="radio" name="quiz1" value="d">' + data[1]['Jawaband'] + '<br>')
 }
          });
  </script>
```

and the data cannot be generated to fill in the quiz, but when i create post method to input something to the database it working perfectly.. Can somebody help me ?